# Why did they not do this to start with?

Tags: lorien-legacies, i-am-number-four

In the latest book in the Lorien Legacies series (The Revenge of Seven), we learn that

> Lorien is not just a planet, but a being that has been moved from planet to planet, bestowing its gifts upon the residents of those planets.  To awaken this being, which was placed on Earth, all the Garde need to do is bring their pendants and inheritances to Sanctuary.

Now, this seems really easy.  Is there any explanation in the books or other canon why they did not do that to begin with, instead of running around as they did?  I can think of a couple theories, but I have not been able to find any explanation in the books.

Comment: I know nothing about this universe, but wouldn't it leave their own worlds defenceless?

Comment: It is not made clear when this happened, but that was my initial thought, as well.  However, when they (the nine Garde children) landed on Earth, their planet had already been conquered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They didn't know. They only found out in The Revenge of Seven, by watching Malcolm's interrogations. They didn't have a lot of information, and all the Cepan died before they could tell them. (Some of them may not have even known).

Even had they known, they couldn't have broken in because it was guarded. They might not have made it in without

> Adam coming with them and distracting all the Mogs.

**Edit:** They also had to wait until they grew up, because the chests only opened after the Legacies started developing. Once that happened, they were no longer together, so they couldn't do anything until they got back together. Then, the survivors didn't know the plan anymore.

Comment: I get why they didn't do it earlier in the series.  But like, as soon as they got to the planet, why not just do it then?

Comment: @DaveJohnson See edit.

Comment: Good edit.  I had forgotten that the chests would not open until their Legacies had developed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with "ike", but I also like to add that previously on the planet Lorien, Setrakus Ra used the Harvestor to harvest the Entity, aka Lorien that resided in Mogadore, in an attempt to grant Legacies to non Garde. If the Cepans told their Garde about the Pheonix Stones to reawaken the Entity, and did just that, then Earth would be in huge trouble. The Mogadorian's huge influence on the Earth's governments as well as Setrakus Ra's technology will basically destroy the Earth's ecosystem by harvesting the Lorien inside, effectively turning it into a barren place like Mogadore.

"Back thousands of years ago, Mogadore once had the Entity residing in it as well. When Setrákus Ra was banished from Lorien, he hid away on Mogadore. Using the energy within that planet, he progressed Mogadore with science, technology, and magic. He called it the Gift. Over hundreds of years, Setrákus Ra harvested so much of this energy that the planet grew absent of it completely. The environment collapsed, and the flora and fauna died out. All that remains of life on Mogadore are Trueborn survivors or Vatborn creations of monstrous beasts and Mogadorian soldiers. Without even a spark of this energy left to awaken, Mogadore cannot be restored (Lorien Legacies Wikia)."

Comment: What is the link of the wiki quote you have there?